# What is the evolutionary advantage of having polymorphisms in MHC?

Tags: genetics, evolution, immunology

The MHC genes are widely polymorphic and hence cause an issue in tissue matching pre-transplantation. Why is there such a polymorphism?

I know that different polymorphisms in MHC can lead to variation in the immune response to the same offender. But then, if there is a difference, shouldn't there be a selection for those that mount a better response?

So, *why the polymorphism*?